How to Train a Wolf in Dungeons & Dragons from dead to new?
In one of my D&D games I tamed a wolf. But in the last game he died. How can I now tame a wolf, but for a new character?

Which edition are you playing?

I guess it's a new wolf for a new character.

Bienvenue! Have a look at the [tour] and at the [help] t get any guidance in asking Q&As on this website!  Your title asks for training a wolf, while the body of the question asks for taming it: can you clarify?

what do you mean "from dead to new"? Which edition d&d is it, how did you do it the previous time and why won't the same method work again?

The same way you did the first time
Regardless of the D&D Edition you are using. It sounds like you successfully tamed a Wolf with your first character, either with the rules of that edition (dnd-5e doesn't have any I am aware of, but maybe older editions did) or through some improvised rulings by your DM.
Why not try this again?
